# Writing data array from a loop into consecutive columns of an excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, loops

This is a part of my code.

```
a = 0;
for i = -3:3
    for j = 1:10
        a(j) = j^i;
    end
    xlswrite('out.xls', a','A1')
end
```

Here I am getting only the last value of `a` in the `out.xlx` file. But I want to fill the values of `a` for each iteration of `i` in consecutive columns of an `Excel` file . Any suggestions ?
**Update**
  I want output like this: -

```
1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1  .....
0.1250   0.2500   0.5000   1  .....
0.0370   0.1111   0.3333   1  .....
0.0156   0.0625   0.2500   1  .....
0.0080   0.0400   0.2000   1  .....
0.0046   0.0278   0.1667   1  .....
0.0029   0.0204   0.1429   1  .....
0.0020   0.0156   0.1250   1  .....
0.0014   0.0123   0.1111   1  .....
0.0010   0.0100   0.1000   1  .....
```

and so on....

Answer (score 1):

You have produced a 1D vector instead of a 2D matrix. This should work:

```
a = 0;
for i = -3:3
    for j = 1:10
        a(j,i+4) = j^i;
    end
    xlswrite('out.xls', a',['A' num2str(i+4) ':J' num2str(i+4)])
end
```

An even better solution would be to vectorize everything:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-3:3,1:10)
a = X.^Y
xlswrite('out.xls', a','A1:J7')
```

@EitanT, @HighPerformanceMark: Changed the answer to reflect your comment. I guess today is not my day - edited 4 times :)

Comment: You need to adjust the subscript `i` to `i + 4` to make sure that it is positive, or alternatively run `i` from 1 to 7 and do `a(j, i) = j ^ (i - 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering the value a in the cell A1. So it is taking only the last value of the array `a`. You need to give the entire range in order to input the complete array.

Try something like this :

```
 xlswrite('out.xls', a','A1:J1')
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Trouble with this answer is that at each value of `i` it will write into cells `A1:J1` leaving the spreadsheet with only the final column of the array.  OP needs to change those `1`s to `i`s too.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnot understand. Is the answer wrong, from the other answers ?