# Writing data on an excel file in a loop

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io

I am running a loop in MatLab and that is creating a set of data, I want to write those data in an excel file after every iteration.

Comment: Have you seen the [`xlswrite` function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [xlswrite1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465-xlswrite1) from MATLAB [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/), which is created for this purpose.

You do not want to do this using the regular `xlswrite`. The reason: The Excel document is loaded, opened and closed every time you run it, and is therefore incredibly slow if you do this in a loop.

`xlswrite1`, will open the document once, and keep it open until you explicitly ask Matlab to close it.

Otherwise, you can store your variables, and write them all, using `xlswrite`, in the end of your loop, which is probably the recommended procedure.

If you do not want to use either of these methods, you should check out these questions:

[Writing data array from a loop into consecutive columns of an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252961/writing-data-array-from-a-loop-into-consecutive-columns-of-an-excel-file?rq=1)

[How to export data from Matlab to excel for a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676763/how-to-export-data-from-matlab-to-excel-for-a-loop?rq=1)

[write information into Excel after each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636567/write-information-into-excel-after-each-loop?rq=1)

Comment: @RobertP. A question. I could not find xlswrite1 command in matlab. Is it a builtin function provided by matlab ? I however did search the net and got this - 

http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465-xlswrite1

Is this what you are talking about ?

Comment: @roni: Yes, it is! The answer links to the page you found.